# Calling a function from the view in yii

Tags: yii

I have this function in my Courses model which grabs the department_id from the url and displays courses based on the department_id

```
public function loadcourses()

{

$data=Courses::model()->findAll('department_id=:department_id', 
array(':department_id'=>(int) $_GET['department_id']));

$data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','course_name');

  //echo "<option>Select Courses</option>";
 foreach($data as $value=>$course_name){

 echo CHtml::tag('input type= "checkbox"' ,   array('value'=>$value,'name'=>'course_id[]'), CHtml::encode($course_name),true);
}}
```

I need it to display in the view as a checkbox so the value can be submitted

i tried this

```
<?php 
Courses::model()->loadcourses()      
echo   $form->checkboxList($model,'course_id',array()

);?>
```

the check boxes display but don't carry any value and it Posts an empty value, I need the values to save in the course_id field